# Unkown error when calling Java applet from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Here's the JavaScript (on an aspx page):

```
function WriteDocument(clientRef, system, branch, category, pdfXML)
{        
    AppletReturnValue = document.DocApplet.WriteDocument(clientRef, apmBROOMS, branch, category, pdfXML);
    if (AppletReturnValue.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('pdfData').value = "";
        CallServer(AppletReturnValue,'');
    }
    PostBackAndDisplayPDF()
}
```

pdfXML is got from pdfData which is a hidden field on the page containing the XML that contains base64 encoded pdf data which is passed to the java applet.  All the other values being passed have within range sensible values.

The XML is like this

```
<Documents>
   <FileName>AFileName</FileName>   
   <PDF>JVBERiDAzOTY1NzMwIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDM5NjU4NDcgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMzk2NTk2</PDF>
</Documents>
```

The contents of the element PDF is a lot bigger than displayed here

The signature of the Java method is:

```
public String WriteDocument(String clientPolicyReference,
                                       int systemType,
                                       int branch,
                                       String category,
                                       String PDFData) throws Exception
```

It seems that when the size of the PDF data gets large the applet fails to be called and the error 'Unknown Error' is thrown in the JS.

The PDF doc the data of which is producing this error is about 4Mb in size.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the WriteDocument method exit successfully? It might be worth adding a try/catch inside if it's not possible to tell.

Comment: Since QA saw this error I've stuck some logging in right at the beginning of the WriteDocument function (it's a signed trusted app so I can write to a log file in the user's home directory) and that doesn't happen.  

I'm beginning to suspect that the failure is happening at the method invocation.  I just don't know why?

I've added some further clarification to the question.

Comment: Does your applet tag contain mayscript="mayscript" ?

Comment: Also you could try to get the form field value from within the applet and not pass it in as parameter?

Comment: No it doesn't.  I wasn't aware of that attribute and it's usage.

I wasn't aware the Java applet could access form elements directly.  That might be something to try.

I'm still a little concerned that I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding chaps but I've sorted the problem.

How?  I took JRE 1.6 update 12 off and stuck update 7 (which is the version we reccomend to those who use our website) on my machine.

Why update 12 stopped working I don't know.  Why update 7 is stable I don't know. [sigh]

It's things like this that make me glad I work mostly with a 'long time between releases' framework like .net.